# Including columns from duplicate rows in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on creating a query which would return one row for each primary key. The question is that in the database there is another table I am trying to join with, and in this other table the primary key from the first table can appear multiple times but with a code which describes what type of information is stored in a column called text_info which stores text related to what the code represents.

For example:

```
PrimaryKey|Code      |text_info
--------------------------------
5555      |1         |1/4/2017
5555      |2         |Approved
```

What I would am trying to get to is a select statement that would return something like this.

```
PrimaryKey|Date      |Status
----------------------------------
5555      |1/4/2017  |Approved
```

I have been trying to join the two tables in various ways but my attempts have always returned multiple rows which I do not want for this query. Any help would be greatly appreciated for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a simple conditional aggregation would do the trick here.  If you have a large and/or variable number of codes, you may have to go DYNAMIC.

```
Select PrimaryKey
      ,Date   = max(case when code=1 then text_info else null end)
      ,Status = max(case when code=2 then text_info else null end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By PrimaryKey
```

Comment: @Ramirez77 Happy it helped